# Can't connect to my router's web panel after changing its IP

Tags: networking, router, ip, connection

I have 2 routers, one which I am using solely for DSL connection to the Internet (WiFi is disabled there) and one for home internal networking. The Internet-connected router had an IP 192.168.2.1 and the home router is at IP 192.168.150.1. I could connect to both routers' web panels without any issue.

Now I changed the IP of the Internet router to 192.168.160.1, everything works as before (no Internet connection issues etc.), besides of the web panel access on the Internet router - if I try to open in web http://192.168.160.1 I just can't do it. If I connect to the router's LAN port with a second notebook it works, surprisingly even after I disconnect from the LAN port and connect to the home WiFi on the second router I can still connect to the web panel successfully as if it would somehow "remember" the route (which doesn't appear logical at all). I also tried to set the subnet on my internal home router to 255.255.0.0 but there is an error then "WAN and LAN should have different IP addresses and subnet." If I change the subnet of my main PC to 255.255.0.0 it doesn't help either, no connection to the web panel of the Internet router.

Please help to resolve this issue, many thanks!

Comment: I would reset the router, allowing the device to be accessible, and make change the IP address again.

Comment: (1) Your paragraph listing what you tried and the results blew my mind.  Can you rewrite it to be clearer about the steps you took and what happened, making each scenario a separate bullet?  Don’t say things like “I just can't do it”; tell us ***what happened**.* (2) Can you ping the router? (3) Can you show us your routing table? (4) I believe that you’ve said that you *can* connect to the router.  When you do that, can you connect to the PC from the router in any way?

Comment: have you tried just using the old IP in your browser? maybe the settings didn't save correctly..

Comment: Hi,

1.What were the subnet masks of the two routers before you started changing it and the IP address?

2.What is the subnet of each router now?

2.Do both the routers still have their DHCP setting enabled?

3.When you IPCONFIG your PC what IP / Subnet do you receive?

4.How are the routers connected?